# Embedd welcome image for Android TV app

Tags: android-layout, android-tv

I want to add a Welcome Image(.jpg/.png) which is dispalyed for a second or two and then the main app-screen is shown.
How can I do this?
I don't want the user to click or swipe or anything..
Just a welcome image for one/two seconds.

PS: Android TV App

Comment: how to solve this for android TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this post by Android Developers. The same method applies to both phones and TVs.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd

Comment: hey this link expired can you share new link or code i got same issue